# Performance Testing using HP ALM

Tags: performance, performance-testing, hp-alm

I am new to testing and HP ALM (have worked with HP Quality Center though). As part of the process, I am required to do performance testing of interfaces belonging to several work streams like HR, Finance, etc. 
There is already a functional testing carried out and test scripts available as part of them. How do I create test scripts as part of the performance testing?